# What do instructions on UbuntuOne wiki for getting Bindwood (Firefox bookmark sync) to work do exactly?

Tags: 10.04, firefox, ubuntu-one, sync

I have the Bindwood extension for Firefox bookmark syncing through UbuntuOne installed on two of my computers and none of the bookmarks have synced between them. The UbuntuOne wiki has instructions for what to do in this situation: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyArentBookmarksSyncing

I'm worried that those instructions might break my existing UbuntuOne configuration. (It was hard enough to get regular file syncing working properly, so I'd rather not risk breaking anything.) But deleting the password entries for CouchDB and removing `~/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini` has me worried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those instruction are harmless, they just renew your DesktopCouch encryption keys.

However Firefox bookmark sync ( and those instructions ) are for Maverick only.

I see this answer is tagged as 10.04, and on Lucid bookmark sync is not enable yet.

Ubuntu Lucid users need to wait for the support to be backported.

Quoted from the wiki:

> Syncing of contacts and bookmarks is working for Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick) users. Maverick users will need to have the latest updates installed. ***Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid) users will have to wait a bit longer for backporting of the CouchDB and Erlang packages.*** We presented the case for backporting CouchDB to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to the Ubuntu Technical Board and the suggestion was to investigate creating a separate, special package that will allow Ubuntu One databases (contacts, bookmarks, etc.) to synchronize once again. We're currently looking into this.

Here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Bookmarks

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for catching that I'm on 10.04. Guess that would explain why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW CouchDB and file syncing on the desktop are only related in that they all come under the Ubuntu One banner of awesomness. I don't think there is anything technically connecting these two things.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 4 will come with a Sync feature built-in, which is capable of syncing not only bookmarks, but also preferences, passwords, history and tabs. If you want to use this feature with older versions of Firefox, you can install Firefox Sync extension:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/

BTW, there are some reports about bindwood causing Firefox excessive CPU usage, freezing and startup delays. I'm not sure if this has been addressed already in recent versions, so keep an eye on it.